# Joining two data frames with intervals misbehaves?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate, tibble

Edit (2019-06): This problem does not exist anymore, as [this issue](https://github.com/r-lib/vctrs/issues/27) has been closed and a related feature implemented. If you now run the code with updated packages, it will work.

I'm trying to find overlapping intervals and decided to join the interval data on itself with `dplyr::left_join()` so that I could compare intervals with `lubridate::int_overlaps()` to every other interval by the same id.

Here's how I expect `left_join()` to behave. The two tibbles with three rows cross to form a [tibble](/questions/tagged/tibble) with 9 rows:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(a = rep("a", 3), b = rep(1, 3)) %>% 
  left_join(tibble(a = rep("a", 3), c = rep(2, 3)))
Joining, by = "a"
# A tibble: 9 x 3
      a     b     c
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     a     1     2
2     a     1     2
3     a     1     2
4     a     1     2
5     a     1     2
6     a     1     2
7     a     1     2
8     a     1     2
9     a     1     2
```

And here's how the same code behaves with intervals. I get nine rows but the rows don't cross like they do above:

```
tibble(a = rep("a", 3), b = rep(make_date(2001) %--% make_date(2002), 3)) %>% 
  left_join(tibble(a = rep("a", 3), c = rep(make_date(2002) %--% make_date(2003))))
Joining, by = "a"
# A tibble: 9 x 3
      a                              b                              c
  <chr>                 <S4: Interval>                 <S4: Interval>
1     a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
2     a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
3     a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
4     a                         NA--NA                         NA--NA
5     a                         NA--NA                         NA--NA
6     a                         NA--NA                         NA--NA
7     a                         NA--NA                         NA--NA
8     a                         NA--NA                         NA--NA
9     a                         NA--NA                         NA--NA
```

I think this is unexpected, but I might be missing something? Or is it a bug?

I'm using [lubridate](/questions/tagged/lubridate) 1.7.1, [tibble](/questions/tagged/tibble) 1.3.4 and [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) 0.7.4.

Comment: I can get around this by not converting start and end dates to intervals before joining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem does not exist anymore, as [this issue](https://github.com/r-lib/vctrs/issues/27) has been closed and a related feature implemented. If you now run the code with updated packages, it will work.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

tibble(a = rep("a", 3), b = rep(make_date(2001) %--% make_date(2002), 3)) %>% 
  left_join(tibble(a = rep("a", 3), c = rep(make_date(2002) %--% make_date(2003))))
#> Joining, by = "a"
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   a     b                              c                             
#>   <chr> <Interval>                     <Interval>                    
#> 1 a     2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
#> 2 a     2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
#> 3 a     2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
#> 4 a     2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
#> 5 a     2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
#> 6 a     2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
#> 7 a     2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
#> 8 a     2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
#> 9 a     2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

**The bug**

The object still contains the relevant information:

```
res <- tibble(a = rep("a", 3), b = rep(make_date(2001) %--% make_date(2002), 3)) %>% 
  left_join(tibble(a = rep("a", 3), c = rep(make_date(2002) %--% make_date(2003)))) 

print.data.frame(res)
# a                              b                              c
# 1 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
# 2 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
# 3 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
# 4 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
# 5 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
# 6 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
# 7 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
# 8 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
# 9 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC

res$c    
# [1] 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
# [5] 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
# [9] 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
```

But when subsetting by indices it doesn't work anywmore :

```
res_df <- as.data.frame(res)

head(res_df)
  a                              b                              c
1 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
2 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
3 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
4 a                         NA--NA                         NA--NA
5 a                         NA--NA                         NA--NA
6 a                         NA--NA                         NA--NA

res_df[4,"c"]
[1] NA--NA
```

and `tibble:::print.tbl` makes use of `head`. That's why the issue is immediately visible with `tibbles` and not with `data.frames`.

Typing `str(res$b)` we see that we only have 3 `start` values for 9 `data` values.

if we do:

```
res_df$b@start <- rep(res_df$b@start,3)
res_df$c@start <- rep(res_df$c@start,3)
```

eveything now print fine:

```
  a                              b                              c
1 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
2 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
3 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
4 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
5 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
6 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
7 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
8 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
9 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
```

**The Solution**

We've seen that `as.data.frame` is not enough, `left_join` is the function messing things up, use `merge` instead:

```
res <- tibble(a = rep("a", 3), b = rep(make_date(2001) %--% make_date(2002), 3)) %>% 
  merge(tibble(a = rep("a", 3), c = rep(make_date(2002) %--% make_date(2003))),
        all.x=TRUE) 

head(res)
# a                              b                              c
# 1 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
# 2 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
# 3 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
# 4 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
# 5 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
# 6 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC

res[4,"c"]
#[1] 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
```

I've reported the issue [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3353)

Comment: There's this [meta issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2432) for better support for non-base types in `dplyr`.
And [this issue](https://github.com/hadley/vctrs/issues/27) in vctrs.

Comment: Thanks. Relevant here is that it seems one might have issues with `dplyr::filter` as well when dealing with lubridate intervals, still because of `start` slot.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a bug in `tibble()`:

```
> AA <- tibble(a = rep("a", 3), b = rep(make_date(2001) %--% make_date(2002), 3))
> class(AA$b)
[1] "Interval"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lubridate"
> AA
Error in round_x - lhs :
  Arithmetic operators undefined for 'Interval' and 'Interval' classes:
  convert one to numeric or a matching time-span class.
```

However:

```
> AA <- as.data.frame(AA)
class(AA$b)
> class(AA$b)
[1] "Interval"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lubridate"
> AA
  a                              b
1 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC
2 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC
3 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC
```

Therefore, this works:

```
> AA <- tibble(a = rep("a", 3), b = rep(make_date(2001) %--% make_date(2002), 3))
> BB <- tibble(a = rep("a", 3), c = rep(make_date(2002) %--% make_date(2003)))
> AA %>% as.data.frame %>% left_join(BB)
Joining, by = "a"
  a                              b                              c
1 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
2 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
3 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
4 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
5 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
6 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
7 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
8 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
9 a 2001-01-01 UTC--2002-01-01 UTC 2002-01-01 UTC--2003-01-01 UTC
```

although this does not:

```
> AA %>% left_join(BB)
Joining, by = "a"
Error in round_x - lhs :
  Arithmetic operators undefined for 'Interval' and 'Interval' classes:
  convert one to numeric or a matching time-span class.
```

Note: I'm using tibble_1.4.1 (same version of lubridate and dplyr as you), on R 3.4.3 for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. With the same package versions as OP, thou on R version 3.3.3, I get identical output as OP, i.e. no error message. Thanks for your work.